# error while processing package 1052720675.itmsp

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am getting these errors while submitting my app to the itunes store.Infact i upload my app last month successfully but now by changing version i am getting these errors. Please help if anyone knows.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too, i solved it after i update  Application Loader and jdk to the latest version!

Comment: I also recently ran into this issue. Both Application Loader and Xcode can perform the itunesconnect transaction, and both can go out of date. You should make sure you are using the latest version of both when doing submissions. My recent experience was getting a java heap error when trying to upload on a machine with an out of date Xcode (6.3, when the current version was 7.2). Updating fixed the issue. This can also occur when using fastlane.tools, which wraps Xcode. You can use xcode-select to chose a newer version of Xcode if you need to keep the old one around.